# Investigate a bash script when it stops without any error

Tags: linux, bash, npm

I am trying to automate the installation of 4 projects, and I encounter an issue with bash that I am not able to understand. When running the script as another user, the scripts stops between 2 steps for no reason that I can think of...

First, this is the script that works and does install the 4 projects successfully:

```sh
install () {
  set -e
  echo "Install $1"
  git clone git@gitlab.com:xxx/$1.git
  cd $1
  npm i
  echo "Install successful"
  cd ..
}

install router
install web
install backend
install file-storage
```

Now, I need to run this script as another user, so I edited the script this way:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sudo su - username <<USER
install () {
  set -e
  echo "Install \$1"

  git clone git@gitlab.com:xxx/\$1.git
  cd \$1
  npm i || echo "Error during install"
  echo "Install successful"
  cd ..
}

install router
install web
install backend
install file-storage
USER
```

Here is the log it gives me (with set -xv). I will sum it up below.

```sh
//...
+ sudo su - username
+ echo 'Install router'
Install router
+ git clone git@gitlab.xxx/router.git
Cloning into 'router'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 60, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (60/60), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
remote: Total 60 (delta 35), reused 35 (delta 23), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (60/60), 29.12 KiB | 3.23 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (35/35), done.
+ cd router
+ npm i

> @root/acme@3.0.9 postinstall /home/username/router/node_modules/@root/acme
> node scripts/postinstall

added 218 packages from 136 contributors and audited 438 packages in 5.894s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

+ echo 'Install successful'
Install successful
+ cd ..
install web
+ install web
+ set -exv
+ echo 'Install web'
Install web
+ git clone git@gitlab.com:xxx/web.git
Cloning into 'web'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 371, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (371/371), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (238/238), done.
remote: Total 371 (delta 152), reused 339 (delta 122), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (371/371), 31.24 MiB | 9.43 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (152/152), done.
+ cd web
+ npm i

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /home/username/web/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@3.6.2 postinstall /home/username/web/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.2 postinstall /home/username/web/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /home/username/web/node_modules/ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)


> parse-domain@2.3.4 postinstall /home/username/web/node_modules/parse-domain
> run-s build:tries


> parse-domain@2.3.4 build:tries /home/username/web/node_modules/parse-domain
> node scripts/build-tries.js

Downloading public suffix list from https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat... (node:8368) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
ok
Writing /home/username/web/node_modules/parse-domain/build/tries/icann.complete.json... ok
Writing /home/username/web/node_modules/parse-domain/build/tries/icann.light.json... ok
Writing /home/username/web/node_modules/parse-domain/build/tries/private.complete.json... ok
Running sanity check... 
Could not update list of known top-level domains for parse-domain because of "Command failed: /usr/bin/node /home/username/web/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
Using possibly outdated prebuilt list from Sat Nov 02 2019

> styled-components@4.4.1 postinstall /home/username/web/node_modules/styled-components
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js || exit 0

Use styled-components at work? Consider supporting our development efforts at https://opencollective.com/styled-components
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1958 packages from 1236 contributors and audited 1816762 packages in 47.021s

52 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

+ echo 'Install successful'
Install successful
+ cd ..
```

There are multiple interesting points:

- The install of the first project seems fine.
- The scripts reach the end of the second install, but doesn't start the next one. It stops for no apparent reason.
- I tried to change the install order. All the projects successfully install before `install web`, but at the end of `install web` the scripts stops and doesn't execute any further command before `USER`.
- If I remove the line `npm i` the problem disappear.
- I changed the line for `npm i || echo "Error during install"` to make sure that `npm i` didn't fail, and as you can see, it didn't.

I don't know what I can do next to investigate deeper...

Comment: Just do `<<'USER'` and you don't need to escape anything.

Comment: Or you could also do `if [[ "$USER" != username ]]; then exec sudo su - username "$0" "$@"; fi` on the beginning of your script, which is sometimes clearer. It checks if the current user is `username`, and if it is not, it runs the script as the user `username`.

Comment: With `<<'USER'` you can leave it as `$1`. No need for \. It will not expand. | Och, yes, indeed you chose the delimeter for the here string the same as variable `USER`. The second method is unrelated to the here string.

Comment: Oh, I see. Here USER is just a token for the `here string` operator. It could be anything and is not related to `$USER`

Comment: It is, inside the subshelll when it is executed. [repl example](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FavoriteAlarmingProcesses).

Comment: Ok, I was, indeed, doing something wrong. Thanks for letting me in on this feature ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `npm i` for the second package is reading input for some reason (perhaps related to all the warning messages it's printing), so it's reading the following `install` commands. Redirect its input to `/dev/null` so it won't have access to the standard input of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sudo su - username <<'USER'
install () {
  set -e
  echo "Install $1"

  git clone git@gitlab.com:xxx/$1.git
  cd $1
  npm i </dev/null || echo "Error during install"
  echo "Install successful"
  cd ..
}

install router
install web
install backend
install file-storage
USER
```

Also, as mentioned in the comment, you can quote the end token in `<<'USER'` -- this treats the here-doc as a single-quoted string, so that `$` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that you are right about the `npm i` reading the input. But I still don't get the part about 'USER'. If I use this, the scripts logs `Install $1` and then fails on the `git clone` for project xxx/$1...

Comment: Quoting `USER` means that `$1` will be passed literally in the here-doc, so you don't have to escape it.

Comment: You were escaping it to prevent the main script from expanding the variable when passing the here-doc to `su`. Quoting the `USER` token has the same effect.

Comment: It should still be expanded by the `install` function.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I messed up between quoting the USER and unescaping the $. A huge thanks for your answer and for letting me discover this feature with here string!

Comment: There is still something that I don't understand: If I run the `npm i` alone, there is no prompting that explains the problem. Moreover, with the first script ran directly as `username` user, the script also works. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an `npm` expert, so I don't really know why it's reading the input in one case but not the other. This is more of a workaround than a real solution.